# Craco, webpack and library creation

Tags: reactjs, webpack, craco

I am creating a small reactjs app which in the end will generate a single .js file (it's basically a chatbot frontend application, which talks to a backend). I have created a react app using `npx create-react-app`, and I have designed everything without problems.

Also I have created a `webpack` powered proof of concept to generate the js file, and that was working too. Long story short, it was all about specifying the output in the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
output: {

        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        library: "StewieWidget",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        filename: "[name].js"
    }
```

Now, the generated app uses react-scripts under the hoods, and not webpack explicitly, to the best of my understanding. So, I don't know how to make it "emerge" and pass the above configuration. Also, while digging on Google, I have found that I could potentially use `craco`, and that's what I did. After reading its configuration, I have seen that, potentially, the webpack documentation can be injected like this:

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    style: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss'),
                require('autoprefixer'),
            ],
        },
    },
    webpack: {
        configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
            webpackConfig.entry = {
                "mylib": './src/index.js'
            }

            webpackConfig.output = {
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
                library: "mylib",
                libraryTarget: "umd",
                umdNamedDefine: true,
                filename: "[name].js"
            }
            console.log(webpackConfig);
            return webpackConfig;
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: false
    }
}
```

which is clearly not working, and if I launch the app with `npm run start --verbose` I see that it hangs like this:

[image]

which is not very helpful. The `start` command simply executes `craco start`.

So, my questions are:

1. is craco che best way to handle this ?
2. should I go straight on webpack usage ? If so, what's a good tutorial for something like I need to do (as a backend dev, webpack is always been a tough topic)

Thanks for help !

Comment: have you installed craco?

did you add the configuration above in `/craco.config.js` of your project?

have you replaced in package.json `"start": "react-scripts start"` with `"start": "craco start"`?

if not I will reply you with all these missing parts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to modify `webpack.config.js` in a react project created with `npx create-react-app` craco is a good solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco .

after the installation you need to replace some lines of your `package.json`

from

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-script start",
    "build": "react-script build",
    "test": "react-script test",
    "eject": "react-script eject"
  },
...
```

to

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
...
```

after that, in your root project add a file called `craco.config.js`

inside the file you can add the code you want.. here just an example of my `craco.config.js` file I normally use (I added additional optional plugins like `craco-alias` and `craco-plugin-scoped-css`.. you don't need them, it's just an example)..

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: require('craco-plugin-scoped-css'),
    },
    {
      plugin: require("craco-alias"),
      options: {
        source: "options",
        baseUrl: "./",
        aliases: {
          "@components": "./src/components",
          "@context": "./src/context",
          "@utils": "./src/utils"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
          crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
          stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        },
      },
    },
    configure: {
      output: {
        publicPath: 'myAppUrl/'
      }
    }
  }
}
```